# want to resize my background image according to cell width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I want to change height and width of my background image according to cell width and height in a table? Here is my code for background images

```
$('td').css('background-image', 'url("seat.png")');
```

Comment: Research [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), specifically `cover` or `contain` depending on your needs

Comment: `td { background-size: cover; }`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please proceed to the Help Centre and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.
And must see How to ask question[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: Thank you guys cover tag works for me but still it is not fit properly in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate the [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property

```
background-size: [Width] [Height];
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPGOrb) is a codepen to visualize how it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('td').css({
'background-image': 'url("seat.png")',
'background-size': '100% 100%'
});
```

I hope it works now.

Comment: It changes only cell width and height not background image size :/

Comment: Hello, i've updated it. Try again with this updated one. Hope this works :)